# How do I step down a 12V pulse width modulation signal to 5V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm, ttl

I want to control my new laser module from my repurposed 3D printer. The laser module has a 12V pin for power, a ground pin and a 5V PWM pin. My board's fan-control port can generate a 12V PWM signal, so I think I should convert it to 5V to control the laser's power.

Are there any special considerations when stepping down PWM signals? I'm worried that a linear converter's capacitors might smooth out my signal or that a buck converter could do something similar. Should I just use a resistor?

Comment: you wouldn't use a regulator to drop the signal voltage. A resistor divider should be sufficient.

Comment: What's the PWM frequency? How long is the connection between the board and the module and is it shielded? What are the output and input impedance?

Comment: Is your 12V pulse a _signal_? Or is it meant to _power_ something? If just a signal, use a voltage divider, i.e. 2 resistors.

Comment: @Reinderien Sigh, I'm afraid I don't have the tools to measure any of those values.

Comment: You don't have a ruler?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The board's 12V output can be used to power a small laser. So ya it's a power source, I just doubt it's powerful enough for my new laser. The laser's 12V input is of course the lead from which it will draw power.

Comment: @Reinderien I do have a ruler. I'm ferly ignorent in this stuff, how should I use it?

Comment: @Reinderien Well I feel like an idiot.. I thought you wanted me to measure impendence with a ruler. The wire is roughly 40 cm long.

Comment: Fan control PWM is typically 25kHz.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Fair enough; assuming that that's the case I've adjusted my time constant accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 40cm long, likely unshielded, possibly non-twisted wire connection is prone to noise. Depending on a large number of factors, this may or may not be a problem. A level-shifting Schmitt trigger with some basic capacitive filtration and Schottky protection diodes will help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foTGsU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This depicts the translation levels before enabling the capacitor:

[image: translation]

This depicts the effect of the filter cap. It's crucial that you understand your PWM frequency and minimum duty cycle before adding this.

If what @BruceAbbott suggests is true and your PWM frequency is 25 kHz, then (depending on expected duties) your transients with a 200pF cap could look like

[image: fast filtration]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a bi-directional level shifter, they are inexpensive, apparently less then unidirectional modules and are readily available. They are not that expensive and the parts are already soldered to a PCB. There are a lot of different ones available. Try searching for"level translator arduino 12V 5V" There are many types and sources available for them. If you want to build it yourself consider using a MM74C914 hex inverter, it will take 25V on its inputs. Simply connect two in series.  You are correct capacitors in the circuit will definitely mess up the PWM signal. Be sure to ground the 4 remaining inputs and leave the outputs open.

Comment: Cool. Another user suggested using a resistor, is there any reason why that would be a bad idea?

Comment: If the 5V input has a high and constant impedance (I assume that it does, but double check in the documentation), a voltage divider (which btw consists of two resistors, not one) should work fine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider Be mindful of what resistor values you choose; Too low R and unneccesarily much power is converted to heat, too high R and your PWM signal will be more susceptible to noise.

Comment: To many unknowns to properly size it. See Dampmaskin's comment, he names a few. Also I have no idea of your skill set and resources available to you.